# The effect of the fields length on the querying time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql database in which I keep information of item and also I keep description.

The thing is that the description column can hold up to 150 chars which I think is long and I wondered if it slows the querying time. Also I wanted to know if its recommended to shorten the size of the int I mean if I have a price which is normally not that big should I limit the column to small/medium int?

The columns are something like this:

```
id   name   category   publisher   mail   price   description
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Store your character data as `varchar()` and not as `char()` and read up on the MySQL documentation on these data types ([here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/char.html)).  This only stores the characters actually in the description, plus a few more bytes of overhead.

As for whether or not the longer fields imply worse-performing queries.  That is a complicated subject.  Obviously, at the extreme, having the maximum size records is going to slow things down versus a 10-byte record.  The reason has to do with I/O performance.  MySQL reads in pages and a page can contain one or more records.  The records on the page are then processed.

The more records that fit on the page, the fewer the I/Os.

But then it gets more complicated, depending on the hardware and the storage engine.  Disks, nowadays, do read-aheads as do operating systems.  So, the next read of a page (if pages are not fragmented and are adjacent to each other) may be much faster than the read of the initial page.  In fact, you might have the next page in memory *before* processing on the first page has completed.  At that point, it doesn't really matter how many records are on each page.

And, 200 bytes for a record is not very big.  You should worry first about getting your application working and second about getting it to meet performance goals.  Along the way, make reasonable choices, such as using `varchar()` instead of `char()` and appropriately sized numerics (you might consider fixed point numeric types rather than float for monetary values).

Answer (score 0):

It is only you that considers 150 long - the database most likely does not, as they're designed to handle much more at once. **Do not consider sacrificing your data for "performance".** If the nature of your application requires you to store up to 150 characters of text at once, don't be afraid to do so, but do look up optimization tips.

Using proper data types, though, can help you save space. For instance, if you have a field which is meant to store values 0 to 20, there's no need for an INT field type. A TINYINT will do.

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html) lists the data types and provides information on how much space they use and how they're managed.

Comment: Agree whole-heartedly with part 1; but disagree strongly with part 2. All hardware is 32 or 64 bit these days, and smaller int representations should only be considered when you have hundreds of millions of them and KNOW that you have a performance problem as a result. Using a smaller int representation for your likely data volumes is as likely to hurt performance as to improve.